# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'NecroBomber.Form1.path'

Tags: c#

im trying to make something that can read a list off accounts from an online .txt file on my website but i keep getting the error

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property '*****.Form1.path'
```

im well and truly stumped as to how to fix the error, the code below is for locating and reading the online file but it refuses to work :(

```
 string path = @"http://mywebsite.com/accounts.txt";
        String[] saUsernames = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

im well and truly confused -_-

Comment: Why are you spamming lanugage tags?  Let's pick *one*.

Comment: 'NecroBomber'? 'Lulzsec'? 'read a list of accounts'? Hmm...nope, nothing suspicious here.

Comment: nope nothing suspicious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the compile-time issue, put the initialization in the constructor. You're simply not allowed to refer to one instance variable from the initializer of another. This is laid down in the C# specification in section 10.5.5.2:

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name. In the example
>
> ```
>    class A
>    {
>        int x = 1;
>        int y = x + 1;   // Error, reference to instance member of this
>    }
> ```
>
> the variable initializer for `y` results in a compile-time error because it references a member of the instance being created.

It's unclear that you even *need* `path` as an instance variable, to be honest:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] userNames;

    public Form1()
    {
        string path = "http://mywebsite.com/accounts.txt";
        userNames = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    }
}
```

Or if it's *always* going to read from that path anyway, you could just inline it:

```
public class Form1
{
    private string[] userNames = 
        File.ReadAllLines("http://mywebsite.com/accounts.txt");

}
```

Not that either of these will actually *work* - `File.ReadAllLines` takes a local filename - *not* a URL. You'll need [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or something similar instead.

I strongly suggest you take a step back and work out what the logical state of the form is. Loading user names from a web site on construction feels like an odd thing for a form to do, to be honest. Additionally, you shouldn't perform potentially long-running operations (like fetching a web page) on the UI thread.

There's a lot to consider about your code - far more than the immediate compilation problem.